# Embedded-RNN with Keras - Issue with Concatenate

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

For audio classification, I would like to try a kind of embedded RNN. Based on the MFCC or the FFT of a 30 second samples, I would like to create a first output for every 1s subsample and then use the 30 outputs to send it to another RNN to get the final prediction. The idea is to fight Vanishing gradient problem by dividing the problem into multi pieces (your opinion is also welcome about this idea, it comes from a visualisation I saw with Wavenet).

This is a representation of the model with only 4 timesteps and 1 layer of LSTM for every level :

[image]

On the following code, I have an issue with the dimension of Concatenate. The input `iX` is (None, 30, 84) and the output is (None, 32). After concatenation on axis 0, I would like a (None, 30, 32).

```python
i1 = Input((30, 84))
l1 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i1)

i2 = Input((30, 84))
l2 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i2)

i3 = Input((30, 84))
l3 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i3)

i4 = Input((30, 84))
l4 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i4)

i5 = Input((30, 84))
l5 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i5)

i6 = Input((30, 84))
l6 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i6)

i7 = Input((30, 84))
l7 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i7)

i8 = Input((30, 84))
l8 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i8)

i9 = Input((30, 84))
l9 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i9)

i10 = Input((30, 84))
l10 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i10)

i11 = Input((30, 84))
l11 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i11)

i12 = Input((30, 84))
l12 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (i12)

# ... up to 30

input_layer = [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6 ,i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12]
first_layer = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6 ,l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12]

# f = Concatenate(axis=0)(first_layer) # Sequential format
f = concatenate(first_layer, axis=0)   # Functional API version

o1 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False) (f)

outputs = Dense(16, activation='softmax') (o1)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=outputs)

model.summary()
```

The error is logical because the shape of (None, 32) is not compatible with LSTM.

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer cu_dnnlstm_13: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Second thing, is there a way to train a model with the same "*cell*" for the first layer. For example on the image, I would like to have **red cells = blue cells = yellow cells = green cells** in term of **cell state**. This is because I would like a time invariant output for a given sound. A specific sound at 0 second should have the same output at the same sound at 10 second. But as it is now, the output will be different based on every *Cell State*.

If this is not possible in Keras, is ther a way to do it with tensorflow ?

Many thanks for your support,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your error, it seems you want to *stack* your tensors (concatenating/stacking tensors along a new dimension), not *concatenate* them (concatenating tensors along an existing dimension).

Using [`K.stack()`](https://keras.io/backend/#stack):

```python
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, CuDNNLSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

# Demonstrating K.stack() on simple tensors:
list_l = [K.variable(np.random.rand(32)) for i in range(30)]
f = K.stack(list_l, axis=0)
print(f)
# > Tensor("stack:0", shape=(30, 32), dtype=float32)

# Actual usage, in your model:
input_layer = [Input(shape=(30, 84)) for n in range(30)]
first_layer = [CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False)(i) for i in input_layer]
f = Lambda(lambda tensors: K.stack(tensors, axis=1))(first_layer)
print(f)
# > Tensor("lambda_1/stack:0", shape=(?, 30, 32), dtype=float32)

o1 = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False)(f)
outputs = Dense(16, activation='softmax') (o1)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
```

It isn't completely clear to me what you mean in your sup. question... Weight sharing for your 1st `CuDNNLSTM` layers maybe (see doc on [Shared Layers](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers))?

If so, you could define your first layers as:

```
cudnn_lstm_first = CuDNNLSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False)
first_layer = [cudnn_lstm_first(i) for i in input_layer]
```

Comment: That's absolutely awesome :) Thanks a lot ! In addition, sharing a LSTM reduced a lot the number of parameters to fine tune from 30 x 15104 to only 15104 (I didn't thought about that upfront).